# Convert text into dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have been given some data in a text format that I would like to convert into a dataframe:

```
text <- "
VALUE Ethnic
1 = 'White - British'
2 = 'White - Irish'
9 = 'White - Other'
;
"
```

I'm looking to convert into a dataframe with a column for the first number and a column for the test in the string. So - in this case, it would be two columns and three rows.

Comment: is this a text file? if so, what format?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(text = trimws(text)) %>% 
  separate_rows(text, sep = "\n") %>%
  filter(text != ";") %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  separate(text, into = c("VALUE", "Ethnic"), sep = "\\s+=\\s+")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  VALUE Ethnic           
  <chr> <chr>            
1 1     'White - British'
2 2     'White - Irish'  
3 9     'White - Other'
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
read.table(text = gsub("=", " ", trimws(text, 
  whitespace = "\n(;\n)*"), fixed = TRUE), header = TRUE)
  VALUE          Ethnic
1     1 White - British
2     2   White - Irish
3     9   White - Other
```

Comment: Base R version can be simplified to this: `read.table(text=gsub('=|;\\n', '', text), header=T)`

Answer (score 0):

## create the years list

years_list = list(range(1986,2020))

## defines the columns separation specified in the layout

columns_width = [(0,2),(2,10),(10,12),(12,24),(24,27),(27,39),(39,49),(49,52),(52,56),(56,69),(69,82),
(82,95),(95,108),(108,121),(121,134),(134,147),(147,152),(152,170),(170,188),(188,201),
(201,202),(202,210),(210,217),(217,230),(230,242),(242,245)]

## defines the english transleted columns according to the layout

columns_header = ['Register Type','Trading Date','BDI Code','Negociation Code','Market Type','Trade Name',
'Specification','Forward Market Term In Days','Currency','Opening Price','Max. Price',
'Min. Price','Mean Price','Last Trade Price','Best Purshase Order Price',
'Best Purshase Sale Price','Numbor Of Trades','Number Of Traded Stocks',
'Volume Of Traded Stocks','Price For Options Market Or Secondary Term Market',
'Price Corrections For Options Market Or Secondary Term Market',
'Due Date For Options Market Or Secondary Term Market','Factor Of Paper Quotatuion',
'Points In Price For Options Market Referenced In Dollar Or Secondary Term',
'ISIN Or Intern Code ','Distribution Number']

## create a empty df that will be filled during the iteration below

years_concat = pd.DataFrame()

## iterate all years

for year in years_list:

```
time_serie = pd.read_fwf('/kaggle/input/bmfbovespas-time-series-19862019/COTAHIST_A'+str(year)+'.txt', 
                     header=None, colspecs=columns_width)

# delete the first and the last lines containing identifiers
# use two comented lines below to see them
# output = pd.DataFrame(np.array([time_serie.iloc[0],time_serie.iloc[-1]]))
# output
time_serie = time_serie.drop(time_serie.index[0])
time_serie = time_serie.drop(time_serie.index[-1])
years_concat = pd.concat([years_concat,time_serie],ignore_index=True)
```

years_concat.columns = columns_header

Comment: This does not answer the question. It looks like you put this answer to the wrong question. Please correct this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).